# Focus first button when there are two buttons in a window

Tags: wpf, button, focus

I use Window to show a dialog, the dialog has two buttons: confirm and cancel, but the cancel button always focus, even i set its `Focusable=False`, while i want to let confirm button to be focused as default, then i can execute the confirmhandler when enter key is pressed.

```
  <Button x:Name="btnConfirm" Content="Confirm" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,100,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="btnConfirm_Click" Focusable="True"/>
  <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" IsDefault="True" Click="btnCancel_Click" Focusable="False"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `IsDefault="True"` from `btnCancel` to `btnConfirm`:

```
<Button x:Name="btnConfirm" ... IsDefault="True" ... />
```

For `btnCancel` you can set `IsCancel`:

```
<Button x:Name="btnCancel" ... IsCancel="True" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Although the initial state of cancel button also is focused, same as confirm button.